# subelements in an arraylist position

Tags: java, arraylist

It is possible to have sub elements in an arraylist position like the one shown in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about arrayList of arrayLists? Or actually more prefferable ArrayList of instances of your specific class which can hold two (or more) subcontexts?

Comment: Is arraylist of arraylist that I am asking. thanks. I didn't know about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ArrayList of Arrays or ArrayLists?

```
ArrayList<Object[]> arrays = new ArrayList<>();
arrays.add(new Object[3]);

ArrayList<ArrayList> arrays = new ArrayList<>();
arrays.add(new ArrayList());
```

Comment: I guess it should be arraylist.